# android -How to make our own push notification service

Tags: android, android-notifications

as you know there are limitations for sending push notifications from parse , for some reasons I can't use google for sending push notifications .

I've web server for each of my applications , is there any way to send pushes from my server ?

I don't want to put a handler to check run minutes to see if there is a new message on my server .

I want to make something like parse or google for sending notifications

How can I do so ?